# Согласование

Tags: согласование

Здравствуйте! Шёл третий день моего отдыха, и я только недавно решил подойти к лифту. Ожидая его прибытие, я начал читать правила использования. Так вот, я наткнулся на второе предложение. 
Меня интересует согласование слов.

*Если в кабину вошли несколько человек*. Да, написал только придаточную часть, главную часть писать не стал. Разве нельзя было бы глагол прошедшего времени поставить на средний род? Мой вариант: *Если в кабину вошло несколько человек*.

Что скажете, уважаемые коллеги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему нельзя? Можно. При наличии в количественно-именном сочетании слова "несколько" возможна постановка сказуемого как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа.

Например:

а) За оградой стояло несколько саней... (Пушкин); Несколько человек оглянулось... (Горький);

б) Несколько дам скорыми шагами ходили взад и вперед по площадке... (Лермонтов); Что могли сделать несколько молодых студентов! (Герцен).

Согласование однородных сказуемых в одном и том же предложении различно в зависимости от того, обозначают они активное действие или пассивное состояние, совместное или раздельное действие: За дверью находилось несколько человек и как будто кого-то отталкивали (Достоевский); Замок бани сломали, несколько человек втиснулось в двери и почти тотчас же вылезли оттуда (Горький).

Answer (score 2):

Возможны оба варианта,поэтому желательно иметь полный и реальный (взятый из жизни) текст.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Эта проблема в грамматике из категории “вечных”, так как не имеет однозначного решения.

Здесь встречаются две противоположные тенденции: согласование по грамматике в ед.ч. и согласование по смыслу во мн.числе, при этом учитывается влияние различных факторов.

1) Позиция сказуемого относительно подлежащего: в препозиции чаще ед.ч.

2) Желание подчеркнуть совокупность действующих лиц/предметов (ед.ч.) или расчлененность действия (мн.ч.).

3) желание подчеркнуть активность действующих лиц - мн.ч.

4) В современной литературе чаще используется форма мн.числа (согласование по смыслу).
Сравнить: "Держи его!" - кричало несколько мужиков. Но: На него кричали несколько человек сразу.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Несколько человек, однако, осталось на месте. В санях сидело несколько человек. Тут же появилось несколько человек.

Несколько человек хлопотали у багажа. Несколько человек ответили.  Несколько человек обернулись. Несколько человек кинулись вслед за коляской.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совместное действие, форма множественного числа - на раздельное совершение действия. 
  При наличии в количественно-именном сочетании слова несколько возможна постановка сказуемого как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа. Например:

а)      За оградой стояло несколько саней... (Пушкин); Несколько человек оглянулось... (Горький); Несколько рыбачьих баркасов заблудилось в море (Куприн);

б)      Несколько дам скорыми шагами ходили взад и вперед по площадке... (Лермонтов); Что могли сделать несколько молодых студентов! (Герцен); Заговорили сначала несколько человек туманно и нетвердо... 
Лишь несколько студентов смогли решить эту задачу; 
Ср. различное согласование однородных сказуемых в одном и том же предложении в зависимости от того, обозначают они активное действие или пассивное состояние, совместное или раздельное действие: За дверью находилось несколько человек и как будто кого-то отталкивали (Достоевский); Замок бани сломали, несколько человек втиснулось в двери и почти тотчас же вылезли оттуда(Горький).
В вашем случае форма мн.ч. предпочтительна, т.к. в лифт входят по отдельности, а не группой.